# Help solving a limit problem with infinity and large exponents

Tags: limits

I'm trying to solve this limit problem, and I have a question.

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac { (1+2 \sqrt[6]x)^{2016} } {1+(2 + (3+4x^6)^7)^8} $$

Can I simply remove the exponents and the root sign and just evaluate the remaining expression to 1/2? Since the numerator and denominator has the same degree?

Comment: Thanks for the help! It's my first time using this site so I didn't know.

Comment: Sure, no problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this limit, you want to factor out the factor that grows the fastest. You have

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac { (1+2 \sqrt[6]x)^{2016} } {1+(2 + (3+4x^6)^7)^8} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac { x^{336}(1/\sqrt[6]{x}+2)^{2016} } {x^{336}(1/x^{336}+(2/x^{42} + (3/x^6+4)^7)^8}. $$

If you cancel the $x^{336}$, you see however that the limit tends to $\frac{2^{2016}}{4^{56}} = 2^{1904}$ and not $1/2$.

Comment: Sorry, I mean $2^{1904}$